Is there any way to debug Angular library from ASP.NET pplication
Angular library which is being consumed as a package and used as a component or sub-feature in Asp.net web application.
The selectors of Angular library component is used as an element in .aspx webforms page, but the session gets logged out automatically intermittently. Is there any way to debug Angular library from ASP.NET webforms application to rectify the issue?
I tried to put the logs in Angular library and those logs I can see in the ASP.NET application - Chrome Dev tools (Console). Need to debug via breakpoints to find out the root cause of the logout issue.

Angular is a front-end, or client side, framework. This means that the development and functionality is performed on your browser, and not by the server.
So the debug step should in chrome side. you say 'the session gets logged out automatically intermittently.' There might be issues related to session management. Consider using Fiddler or other tools, this can help you understand if there are any specific requests or responses that are causing the session to expire or logout.
